# Facebook Graph API and Yahoo Pipes : Getting News Feed

Tags: facebook, yahoo-pipes, yql, facebook-graph-api

I know that the following is used to request the news feed

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token?...
```

Which returns the set in json.

What is the way to get this into a pipe ? I have tried fetching the data but `robots.txt` does not allow it. I also tried building the url from scratch yields errors as well.

I have been able to get public objects to work with yql

```
select * from json 
         where url="https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post"
```

What about about those that require the `access_token` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple proxy script (on PHP, ASP .NET or something else), which would transfer request from Yahoo!Pipes to Facebook and return back Facebook's response.